# Android SDK and Eclipse Virtual device not launching

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have just installed eclipse with the andriod sdk. I have completed all suggested steps. When I attempt to launch the Emulator widows returns emulator arm stopped working can anyone help me with this I cannont test my .apk without it as I do not have an android device.

Comment: what steps have you done? which tutorial?

Comment: Uninstall everything and try again.

Comment: Do you restart your pc and tried again?

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a virtual device or the emulator. m guessing u have not.
Start AVD manager,u can find it in the same folder where the 'android sdk manager' resides. 
Choose the create new option and create a emulator. This will create the emulator and the applications that you write on eclipse will run on this emulator.
Note : the emulator will take a few moments to run, the first time. So don assume that its not working.